# Office Action Codes

Tags: office-action, code

Like for US, CTNF (non-final rejection and CTFR (final rejection) are the office action codes where we can search for 102 and 103 rejection info. I want to check for EP, JP, CN and KR countries office action codes. Example 1703 (European search opinion) where we can get the X and Y citation which is equivalant to 102 and 103 in USPTO. So for EP the office action code is 1703. Similarly I want to know for other countries such as CN, JP and KR.